Centered wider slide in Swiper-React
I'm trying to increase width of centered slide using React and Swiper (not obligatory).
But when I'm doing this like just increasing width of slide container Swiper obviously moves another slides to the right:
<div style={{height: '25rem'}}>
  <Swiper
    slidesPerView={4}
    spaceBetween={30}
    centeredSlides={true}
    pagination={{
      clickable: true,
    }}
    modules={[Pagination]}
  >
    <SwiperSlide style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    ...
    <SwiperSlide style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</div>

Is there a way to fix this and make slider looks like on the screenshot?

